# visitors IP or visitor IPs or visitors IPs

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

Which one is correct?

- visitor**s** IP
- visitor IP**s**
- visitor**s** IP**s**

To make things clear: a number of users visit a website. I want to say *each IP of each visitor* as a whole.

In other words what do you call this pack:
[IP1, IP2, IP3, ...]

Comment: ...or D) _none_ of the above.

Comment: And are you talking about one visitor (_visitor's IPs_) or multiple visitors (visitors' IPs)?  This assumes there are multiple IPs per visitor.

Comment: One IP per visitor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call that pack a list of *visitors' IP addresses*

Visitors because there are multiple visitors.

Apostrophe because those IP addresses are considered to be belonging to the visitors.

*IP addresses* rather than just IPs because it's more correct. This part is optional, I guess...

Answer (score 2):

"Visitors' IPs" is correct.

"Visitors IP" is not correct because each visitor has his/her own IP, which means that "IP" should be plural.

"Visitor IPs" is less specific than you may want to be because multiple visitors are present. This seems to only imply you have multiple IP addresses and not necessarily visitors to go with them.

"Visitors' IPs" is correct because it correctly shows there are multiple visitors and multiple IPs. This allows for each visitor to have at least one IP address to his/herself.

I also suggest you write "Visitors' IP Addresses" instead of "visitors' IPs."

You can find more help at: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/general_writing_introduction.html

Comment: "Visitor IPs" seems acceptable to me -- compare "apple cores" or "egg crates".

Comment: @nollidge I agree, thanks for your examples. Altering my answer to accommodate your point. I would love to earn back your vote!